# Error Unexpected token "operator" of value "%" in twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig

Im trying to do a simple for loop in twig:

```
{{% for category in ['Action','Drama','Comedy','Anime','Adults','Science fiction'] %}}
   <p class="lead"><a href="">{{category}}</a></p>
{{% endfor %}}
```

but twig is giving me this error message and I cant see why: Unexpected token "operator" of value "%" in MoviesBundle:Default:index.html.twig at line 129.

I try this way array['Action','Drama','Comedy','Anime','Adults','Science fiction'] with the same result. a little help will be nice. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `for` and `endfor` the curly brackets must be **single**:

```
{% for category in ['Action','Drama','Comedy','Anime','Adults','Science fiction'] %}
   <p class="lead"><a href="">{{category}}</a></p>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{% for category in ['Action','Drama','Comedy','Anime','Adults','Science fiction'] %}
<p class="lead"><a href="">{{category}}</a></p>
{% endfor %}
```

curly brackets should be single. double bracket is used only for printing the variable and arrays.